# MySQL Regex to match wildcard and occurances

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Relatively easy one here but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I have a load of documents I need to use a REGEX search for, here's the query:

```
select * from myTable WHERE documentText REGEXP '(PHP){5}'
```

Now I **know** for sure there are at least 5 records that have over 5 mentions of PHP in them yet if I set the above any higher than 1 I get nothing?

What am I missing?

EDIT
After discussing as below REGEX is far too slow for what I want to achieve, LIKE is actually far quicker.

Thanks

Marc

Comment: **To be more precise, a{n} matches exactly n instances of a**

Comment: Ahh idiot, yeah gotcha can I do a minimum number easily?

Comment: **{5,}** = 5 or more

Answer (score 0):

**{5}** matches exactly 5 instances.
**{5,}** matches 5 or more instances

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Oh what a silly man I am, been reading all day must have no absorbed that, thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually (PHP){4,} still doesn't give the expected result

Comment: Ah hold on (PHP){4,} will look for PHP repeated at least 4 times together, this is a large document so PHP could occur anywhere

Comment: ahh, well that's a different kettle of fish - you are perhaps looking for full text search (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) -so  you can rank how relevant a match is ?

Comment: Yeah I was building a different kind of search so the user can specify the number of matches per keyword

Comment: What about this: (PHP(.*)){10,}

Comment: Although thats very slow.

Comment: Well I definately over complicated that one, thats a ton quicker - didn't even think of that